# Windows 10 1803 Requires SMB2 or Higher

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-10, server-message-block

I tried to change the computer-name on a Windows 10 (1803) workstation and got this error:

[image]

The link mentioned goes [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=852747).

What's the best way to handle this (in a way where I won't see this again) on our Active Directory 2008R2 network?

Comment: It turns out, that one of our domain controller is still running Windows Server 2003. If I reboot that server, while attempting to add a computer to the domain, the task succeeds, because that old server doesn't have the opportunity to service the request while it is rebooting (and instead the Windows 2008 R2 services the request successfully). So, this is a temporary work-around you can do until you're able to upgrade the outdated secondary domain controller.

Answer (score 3):

Activate SMBv2 support on your DC (For the NETLOGON and SYSVOL's volume) (Check there HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters)

I suspect only SMBv1 is activated at the moment we talk.

(Or re-activate SMBv1 on the Windows 10 in the short term)

Newest Windows 10 build remove SMBv1 [support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows) for security reason.

Comment: Your instructions got me [here](http://neartalk.com/ss/2018-08-27_001_2773x692.png), but what's next?

Comment: I'm reading [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and).

Comment: @LonnieBest The printscreen is from the server or the Win10 ? If from the server, If no SMB key is present, it  mean you need to make a DWORD key, SMB1 with a 0 value. That will force SMB2 usage and you would need a restart. I don't know if you have other domain controller too on the other side, please check to be sure the impact is not too big. A note, on SMBv2, shared  MSAccess DB can act incorectly, so be aware it can have some unwanted impact. (I don't know what role your DC has..)

Comment: That screenshot was from the server. Unfortunately, there actually is an MS Access database being served via one of the file shares on the 2008R2 AD server , and there is another AD server (2003R2 unfortunately). It seems I should hold off until I learn more about how this might effect us.

Comment: @LonnieBest Then in the short term you can re-activate smbv1 support on the windows 10. Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off > check the box for "SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support".